# WPF DatePicker default to today's date

Tags: wpf, datepicker

WPF DatePicker always show 'Show Calendar' by default. I want it to show current/todays date. How do I do that. I tried doing something like the below in the constructor but it won't work,

```
datePicker.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

or

```
datePicker.DisplayDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

Answer (score 168, accepted):

please try with this ....

```
<my:DatePicker SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"/>
```

add this reference

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Comment: How would that be done if I'm to set the date for tomorrow (or any other day that is to be dynamically calculated)? I want to use XAML for that.

Comment: Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16463217/setting-a-static-datetime-in-wpf-xaml

Comment: Note that the 'app' prefix in this case is the namespace of the helper class, e.g. xmlns:app="clr-namespace:AppName.WPFHelpers"  where namespace AppName.WPFHelpers { public static class DateTimeHelper.....

Comment: how to set only Year & month?

Answer (score 23):

The below works for me. (dpDate is my DatePicker control)

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dpDate.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of options...

You could copy the entire style for the DatePicker control and edit the XAML and use that as the default resource making the TargetType DatePicker which will force it to be used across the application.

You could also edit the style locally and place your own TextBox in the style and hide the DatePickerTextBox and then setup the binding appropriately.

Some in depth conversation [here](http://wpf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=39630) with a pretty good explanation by ericf at the top.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DatePicker's Text property to get or set the date
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.text.aspx

I'm developing with IronPython and do it as so

```
self.root.FindName('DatePicker').Text = time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is you are attempting to access date with time. that doesn't work.

the date today is represented in "DateTime.Today"

Answer (score 0):

datePicker.SelectedDate=DateTime.Now;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

If you need to set the date programmatically (or in the code behind) you could try...

```
datePicker.Text = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString();
```