# Displays the current date in DatePicker in WPF

Tags: wpf

I'm on the WPF is a form of control DatePicker (don't show "Select Date" in textbox of DatePicker) how to do that when the form loads in DatePicker displays the current date

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885912/wpf-datepicker-default-to-todays-date

Answer (score 3):

just try this in SelectedDate property and refer the  mscorlib

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 


SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"
```

Answer (score 3):

Just try this in SelectedDate property and refer to mscorlib:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Then after this, add in datepicker:

```
SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"
```