# Why does default value for DatePicker SelectedDate cause StackOverflow exception?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datepicker, stack-overflow

I'm new to WPF (and stackoverflow!) and have been searching for a simple way to set the default date in a DatePicker control.  I would like to display the current date when the main view is opened, and prefer to do this through XAML only.

Many of the posts I've found suggest inserting a static value into the XAML using markup extension and namespace reference like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885912/wpf-datepicker-default-to-todays-date), which I have tried without success, the result being a StackOverflow exception:  "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

I can't figure out what I've done wrong, or if there's some kind of recursion crashing my application?  Any and all help is appreciated.

MainView XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Tasks.MainView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"        
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tasks"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Tasks.ViewModel"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="TASK LIST" Height="600" Width="900">
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>          
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>        
    <DatePicker x:Name="dpSelectedDate" SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Today}" />        
</Grid>
```

Comment: So if you remove the `DatePicker` line you no longer get the exception? Also can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @rudeboy nothing wrong with the datepicker, check your MainView constructor

Comment: @Quantic If I remove the DatePicker line entirely or just remove the SelectedDate property the application loads and there is no exception.  No real stack trace that I can see to post except this message:  "The maximum number of stack frames supported by Visual Studio has been exceeded."  And the message "There is no code to show because all threads were executing external code."

Comment: @patrickInMpls I checked the MainView constructor but no code there except InitializeComponent();

Comment: If I set the SelectedDate value through the constructor in the code behind like this dpSelectedDate.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today; everything works as expected.

Comment: Can you try this `SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"/>`.

Comment: @ElavarasanM ok I tried that and got the same exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additional errors began to appear in other projects, so I decided to reimage my workstation and reinstall Visual Studio which resolved the issue I was having. Thanks to all for the comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code and for me it works.
Are you sure that the StackOverflowException is caused by the SelectedDate property? Try to remove the DataContext of the Window:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I tried removing the window's DataContext as suggested and still got the exception.

Comment: Mhhhh, you need to isolate the problem. Try to create a new WPF application, and copy & paste only the XAML required. Do you get the exception?

Comment: You're correct, just not sure how to isolate.  New test projects throw the exception in both VS2013 and VS2015. Tested on a coworkers machine with no problems.

Comment: Maybe is something regarding your culture, language or region? Try to see your current culture with System.Threading.Thread.CurrentCulture and System.Threading.Thread.CurrentUICulture.

Comment: System.Threading.Thread.CurrentCulture:  **en-CA**      System.Threading.Thread.CurrentUICulture:  **en-US**