# DatePicker displays default date 1/1/0001 - C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I am using a datepicker in C# WPF and it is defined in XAML as:

```
  <DatePicker  x:Name="TheDate"  Width="200" Text="{Binding ReportPlanningDate ,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" IsTodayHighlighted="True" />
```

Binding property `ReportPlanningDate` is defined as:

```
public DateTime ReportPlanningDate
        {
            get { return _ReportPlanningDate; }
            set
            {
                if (_ReportPlanningDate == value) return;
                _ReportPlanningDate = value;
                PlanningDate = _ReportPlanningDate;
                OnPropertyChanged("ReportPlanningDate");
            }
        }
        public DateTime _ReportPlanningDate;
        public DateTime PlanningDate;
```

Even though I set `IsTodayHighlighted` to `True`, it displays `1/1/0001`. What am I missing here?

Comment: If you place a breakpoint within `set`, does it get hit during the load of your page? If yes, what is the value of `value`?

Comment: It says: value = {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}  @Alexei

Comment: Then,  make sure you set it to current date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IsTodayHighlighted` only highlights current date (if you scroll calendar to current day, you will see it is highlighted) but it doesn't select it.
If you have property `Text` bound to a property of ViewModel, it is data driven, so it will select date based on data. As data is not set it has default value (1.1.0001.).
To solve this, assign default value:

```
public DateTime _ReportPlanningDate = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: You can set `_ReportPlanningDate` to `DateTime.Now.Date` also in the constructor of the ViewModel, where you have the possibility to write a more elaborated logic. Notice that the backing field should be **private, not public**

Answer (score 1):

`IsTodayHighlighted` is only used to highlight today's date. Not setting the default date. If you want to set the default date, you need to set the `SelectedDate` property.

```
<my:DatePicker SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"/>
```

Add this reference if needed.

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

As mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885912/wpf-datepicker-default-to-todays-date?rq=1).

Comment: but this is **not** MVVM oriented, a *binding* is expected for `SelectedDate`

Answer (score 1):

Mark the backing field as private

```
private DateTime _ReportPlanningDate; // only the property is public
//public DateTime PlanningDate; what's this?
```

You can set it in the constructor of the ViewModel

```
public class MyVM : ViewModelBase {
    public MvVM() {
        _ReportPlanningDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

and you should bind the selected date of the date picker

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate={Binding ReportPlanningDate}
```

Comment: PlanningDate is being elsewhere in the project. thnx for the note on "private".