# C# WPF DatePicker value when opened picker

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I would like to ask you about any trick with DatePicker. I have default value DateTime.MinValue, but I want, when I open the DatePicker, to show actual Date, so I dont have to click milion times to find actual date.

Is there any solution?

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding RecievedDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I believe you can find the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885912/wpf-datepicker-default-to-todays-date

Comment: @mjwills Its may not be a duplicate of that because they may want to bind to SelectedDate using some date other than now

Comment: @Fejac could you post your RecievedDate code?

Comment: Is `RecievedDate` a typo? Did you mean to put `ReceivedDate`?

Comment: Its a typo. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you are doing is correct so for some reason the binding must be failing (check output window) or you need to update the binding via INotifyPropertyChanged